# plotting multiple plots using R

Tags: r

```
ID         ARM  DOSE    DATE    TIME    gender  age weight  crcl    DV  CMT
227000018   2   NA    3/8/2011  10:20   Female  30    149   147     0   1
227000018   2   NA    3/8/2011      .   Female  30    149   147     .   2
227000018   2   NA    3/8/2011      .   Female  30    149   147     .   3
227000018   2   300   3/8/2011  11:15        .   .      .     .     .   .
227000018   2   NA    3/11/2011 9:00    Female  30    149   147    5.6  1
227000018   2   NA    3/11/2011     .   Female  30    149   147     .   2
227000018   2   NA    3/11/2011     .   Female  30    149   147     .   3
227000018   2   300   3/11/2011 9:26    .        .     .    .       .   .
227000018   2   NA    3/15/2011 9:25    Female  30    149   147    4.1  1
227000018   2   NA    3/15/2011     .   Female  30    149   147     .   2
227000018   2   NA    3/15/2011     .   Female  30    149   147     .   3
227000018   2   300   3/15/2011 9:40    .        .      .   .       .   .
227000018   2   300   3/18/2011 9:36    .        .      .   .       .   .
```

DV = dependent variable, ID = individual, CMT = compartments

How can I show in a single plot if possible. Each ID as a line, Time(or days) on X-axis with DV from CMT 1 (or 2 or 3) on Y-axis?

As you see in the data, every individual starts on a particular date and dose was given at certain time and date.

I have tried using

```
for (i in unique(plots$ID))
{
plot(plots$DATE[plots$ID==i],plots$DV[plots$ID==i,CMT==1],xlab="DATE",ylab="DV",pch=19)
}
```

Comment: Look at the "lines" function. You would call the plot, defining the axis range and use type="n" (blank plot). Then using lines, add lines for each ID using your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plots[plots$CMT==1,],aes(x=TIME,y=DV,group=ID))+geom_line()
```

If you want to decrease the opacity

```
     library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plots[plots$CMT==1,],aes(x=TIME,y=DV,group=ID))+geom_line(alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you Adiana, the code worked but the plot is not legible and could not paste it here.

Comment: If the lines are overplot, you can decrease the opacity. See the change